# PHP search through SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to organize this into a table with its own column but every time I try, I get something really messy or completely wrong. If I could get some help on implementing a table from the SQL that would be great. For example look at this image:

http://bfast.elementfx.com/design/table.JPG

Here is the code

```
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // localhost will be used in most cases
$dbUser = 'root'; 
$dbPass = 'root';
$dbDatabase = 'root'; // the database you put the table into.
$con = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or trigger_error("Failed to connect to MySQL Server. Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbDatabase) or trigger_error("Failed to connect to database {$dbDatabase}. Error: " . mysql_error());

$error = array();
$results = array();

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
   $searchTerms = trim($_GET['search']);
   $searchTerms = strip_tags($searchTerms); // remove any html/javascript.

   if (strlen($searchTerms) < 2) {
      $error[] = "Search terms must be longer than 2 characters.";
   }else {
      $searchTermDB = mysql_real_escape_string($searchTerms); // prevent sql injection.
   }

   // If there are no errors, lets get the search going.
   if (count($error) < 1) {
      $searchSQL = "SELECT brandname, manufacturer, distributor, modelnumber, date, expirey FROM productlist WHERE ";

      // grab the search types.
      $types = array();
      $types[] = isset($_GET['Brand Name'])?"`brandname` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
      $types[] = isset($_GET['Manufacturer'])?"`manufacturer` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
      $types[] = isset($_GET['distributor'])?"`distributor` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
      $types[] = isset($_GET['modelnumber'])?"`modelnumber` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
      $types[] = isset($_GET['E'])?"`E` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';
      $types[] = isset($_GET['F'])?"`F` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'":'';

      $types = array_filter($types, "removeEmpty"); // removes any item that was empty (not checked)

      if (count($types) < 1)
         $types[] = "`brandname` LIKE '%{$searchTermDB}%'"; // use the body as a default search if none are checked

          $andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'OR';
      $searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . " ORDER BY `brandname`"; // order by title.

      $searchResult = mysql_query($searchSQL) or trigger_error("There was an error.<br/>" . mysql_error() . "<br />SQL Was: {$searchSQL}");

      if (mysql_num_rows($searchResult) < 1) {
         $error[] = "The search term provided {$searchTerms} yielded no results.";
      }else {
         $results = array(); // the result array
         $i = 1;
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)) {
            $results[] = "{$i}: <b>Brand Name:</b>  {$row['brandname']}<br /><b>Distributor:</b>  {$row['distributor']}<br /><b>Manufacturer:</b>  {$row['manufacturer']} <br /><b>Model Number:</b>  {$row['modelnumber']}<br /><b>Certifying Agency:</b>  {$row['E']} {$row['F']}<br /><br /><br />";
            $i++;
         }
```

Comment: mysql_connect is deprecated since PHP version 5.5.0. Use mysqli!

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific, I really do not understand what you're asking for. But as a starting point, it appears from just glancing at your code that there is a missing ending curly bracket "}" in your last 'else' statement, which may be creating issue. You say: "i am trying to organize this into a table with its own column but every time i try i get something really messy or completely wrong", but what is "this", and how are we supposed to help if you don't describe what you mean by "messy of completely wrong"? That could mean anything...

Comment: its showing like this 1:Brand Name: Bio®
Distributor: Pinn
Manufacturer: Bio Inc.
Model Number: Bio\® M 0.5-N                        what i want it to do is be in a table with each one saying manufacturer distributor model number in its own column and have each search show in a clean table instead of current layout. does this make a bit more sence.
Certifying Agency: Type 3

Answer (score 0):

The error is in giving space at `$andOr` variable, see

```
$andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?'AND':'OR'; // You cannot implode them without giving space
$searchSQL .= implode(" {$andOr} ", $types) . " ORDER BY `brandname`";
```

and the fixed code is:

```
$andOr = isset($_GET['matchall'])?' AND ':' OR '; // I give space to them
$searchSQL .= implode($andOr, $types) . " ORDER BY `brandname`"; // I call $andOr variable directly without `{}`
```

So, is still any error found ?

Comment: havent had any errors, i still need to figure out how to make it all display in a table in its own column like the sql database like in the picture description